# Converting Histogram Values to Int Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, histogram

everyone. I created an histogram with by using an array with a size of 1x1000 and its values range from 0 to 99. I want to store histograms values as an int array. However, when I run the program I got the following results for the program(the numeric values are different for everyone since its random):

> (array([ 93., 101., 119.,  91.,  97., 110., 102., 111.,  85.,  91.]), array([ 0. ,  9.9, 19.8, 29.7, 39.6, 49.5, 59.4, 69.3, 79.2, 89.1, 99. ]), )

I want to get a result like this:

> [ 93 101 119 91 97 110 102 111 85 91]

Can you help? Also what kind of array I am getting as a result? It doesn't look like anything I have ever seen before

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randint(100, size=1000)   
y = plt.hist(x,10)  

print(y)
```

Comment: You get a tuple back. To access the result you want, us `y[0]`. I don't see any solid reason why you want the output without decimal. Nevertheless you can convert each element of `y[0]` using `int()` if you wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with random numbers you can use `np.random.seed(n)` to ensure that others who run your code have the same numbers.

According to the docs you get both the bin values and the bin edges back from `plt.hist()`.

Take a look at the following:

```
print(y[0])
 [109. 109.  82. 117.  84. 101.  80. 108. 110. 100.]

[type(i) for i in y[0]]
 [<class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>]
```

You can assign `y[0]` to whatever you'd like and you should be good to go.